# How to avoid code duplication in Flask web application

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to change some variable in base html-template which other html pages inherite from after entering user in personal account.

The idea is as follows:

- there is base html template and there depends on user status (logged in or logged out) are buttons `Registration` and `Enter`/`Exit`.
- if user is logged in then I want `Enter` button and `Registration` button to be dissappeared and instead of `Enter` button I want `Exit` button to be there
- in case if user is not logged in then two buttons should be: `Enter` and `Registration`

I managed to accomplish this task using flask, jinja2 and python but my backend code looks unbearably ugly because there is too much of duplication

Here is my python code:

this function executes before user gets to any html page and determines its status

```
from flask import g
from flask import render_template
@app.url_value_preprocessor
def send_user_login_status(endpoint, values):
    if current_user.is_authenticated: # if logged in
        g.login_button_class = u'logout'
        g.login_button = u'Exit'         

        g.signin_button = u''
        g.signin_button_class = u'signout'
    else: # if not logged in
        g.login_button_class = u'login'
        g.login_button = u'Enter'


        g.signin_button = u'Registration'
        g.signin_button_class = u'signin'

    return render_template("base.html",
                           login_button=g.login_button,                               
                           login_button_class=g.login_button_class,
                           signin_button=g.signin_button,
                           signin_button_class=g.signin_button_class,
                           )
```

And now I must every time pass variables to html page in order this page to be with needed buttons.

For example home page:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html",
                           login_button=g.login_button,                                                           
                           login_button_class=g.login_button_class,
                           signin_button=g.signin_button,
                           signin_button_class=g.signin_button_class,                           
                           )
```

or about us page:

```
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    # send_user_login_status()
    return render_template("about.html",
                           login_button=g.login_button,                            
                           login_button_class=g.login_button_class,
                           signin_button=g.signin_button,
                           signin_button_class=g.signin_button_class,
                         )
```

This is my python logout function:

```
@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    login_status = logout_user()
    if login_status:
        g.login_button_class = u'login'
        g.login_button = u'Enter'


        g.signin_button = u'Registration'
        g.signin_button_class = u'signin'


        jsonify({'result': True})
        return redirect('/')
```

**And as you can see there is too much of duplication because I need to pass this depends-on-login-status variables to each html page.**

Whereas html code looks nice:

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
         <nav id="menu">
          <ul class="right">
                    <li class="{{ login_button_class }}"> {{ login_button }}</li>
                    <li class="{{ signin_button_class }}">{{ signin_button }}</li>
                </ul>
         </nav>
         <main>

                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
         </main>

</body>
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>Home</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

about.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>About</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it this way:

```
def render_sidebar_template(tmpl_name, **kwargs):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:  # если залогинен
        trigger_logged_id()
    else:  # иначе
        trigger_logged_out()
    return render_template(tmpl_name,
                           login_button=g.login_button,
                           login_sidebar_class=g.login_sidebar_class,
                           login_button_class=g.login_button_class,
                           signin_button=g.signin_button,
                           signin_button_class=g.signin_button_class,
                           signin_sidebar_class=g.signin_sidebar_class,
                           personal_account=g.personal_account,
                           **kwargs)
```

And now instead of return render_template(...) I call the above function

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_sidebar_template("index.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your logic directly into the base template - it's easier to understand the intention and maintain in the long run. The logic will run on every page that extends the base page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
   <nav id="menu">
      <ul class="right">
        {% if current_user.is_authenicated %}
            <li class="login">Enter</li>
            <li class="signin">Registration</li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="logout">Exit</li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
<main>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</main>

</body>
```